# Can anyone identify the games featured in this video?

Tags: game-identification

I came across this

and noticed several games that I couldn’t identify. I was able to recognize The Stanley Parable, Team Fortress 2, Minecraft, and SCP, as well as some of the Persona games. Could anyone help me name the rest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the games I can recognize (with YT comment section help):

1. Persona 1
2. Minecraft
3. Garry's Mod
4. VRChat
5. Persona 4
6. Persona 5
7. Team Fortress 2
8. The Stanley Parable
9. SCP: Containment Breach

Comment: This might be the case of a community wiki answer

Comment: Those two missing ones lack any unique identifiable elements. The fourth one may be from an asset pack, rather than an existing game.

Comment: The video comments mention "White Day" and "Last Judgement"

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft comments are disabled for me due to restrictions. Do you mean Lost Judgment?

Comment: A couple comments say #4 is a VRChat world; one specifies that it's called "Midnight School". Supposedly according to the video creator, but I haven't seen that comment and YT really sucks to dig through. RE: White Day, a comment says the lights should be off if it's that game, but IDK which # that is referring to.

Comment: @l3l_aze VRChat seems correct for #4, and for #3 a comment says it's a custom map of Garry's mod (also according to the creator)